# Show string in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to learn Vue.js, and am playing around with the [modal component example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).  I'm trying to change it up a bit so that the button clicked can provide data to the component (I'm *very* new to this so my terminology may be off).

I've updated the app to be:

```
// start app
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false,
    title: 'Default Title'
  },
  methods: {
    modalInit: function(title) {
      //this.title = title;
      this.showModal = true;
    }
  }
})
```

The updates were mainly so that I can change the title within the modal based on the button clicked, here is the update to the button:

```
<button id="show-modal"@click="modalInit('A title')">Show Modal</button>
```

The relevant portion of the x-template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
</div>
```

Not sure if it matters, but the component is:

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
})
```

In this state, the modal will open fine but the title won't be there and I get the console error: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.`

I can't figure out to to properly "declare reactive data properties in the data option".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified a `title` property for the root component. But, the modal component does not have a `title` property. Add it like this:

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Default Title"
    }
  }
})
```

---

If you want to pass in a dynamic value for `title`, make it a property instead:

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  template: '#modal-template',
  props: ['title']
})
```

Then, you can pass the value for the title in the component tag:

```
<modal :title="dynamicTitle"></modal>
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  That answers the question but I guess I also needed to ask how to dynamically update that from the button, I'll dig into that and ask another question if I need to.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell see my edit. You can make title a prop on the modal component and pass in a property value on the parent level.

Comment: Thanks.  That's good to know, but I'm not sure that's what I need (sorry for not knowing enough about it to ask a proper question)...Imagine a list of buttons, each button opens the same modal, but the content of the modal is different based on the button pressed.  Because of this, the triggering element is responsible for setting, for example, the `title`.  All that being said, you did answer the question I asked :D

Comment: @ChrisRockwell maybe this will help https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmJgGv. This uses [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) instead of props.